# To express some correspondence

Tags: phrase-request

I have 3 figures from left to right.

The value of some parameter is 401, 301, 201 in the three figures.

I want to express the fact that the 401 corresponds to the left-most one, 301 to the middle one, 201 to the right-most one.

Is the following sentence ok?

'The lattice size N is 401, 301, 201 in the three figures successively'.

Or is there any better way?

Comment: If you do mention them before in the right order, you can use "respectively" - "The figures A, B, C... have lattice sizes that are 401, 301, 201 respectively." You can also place "respectively" before the values.

Comment: +1 for @MorganFR's "respectively", which sounds better to my ear than "successively".  *Successively* implies time to me, not position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is correct to say it like this:

> The lattice size represented in figure N is 401, 301 and 201 -from left to right-.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If the views and references are in order, "from the left" or "from the right" is sufficient.